# How to navigate to another page with id param on Ag-grid?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

I am trying to edit the record displaying in Ag-Grid table. I want to navigate to edit page while clicking on particular cell of Ag-grid and the ID param of that record has to be pushed for populating edit page.
My app is built with Vue.Js .Can any one help with solution to this? Please.!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. I hope it might work for you as well.

```
{
          headerName: "ID",
          field: "idvalue",
          cellRenderer: params => {
            const route = {
              name: "editpage",  // name will be same as stated in the route by you
              params: { id: params.value } 
            };

            const link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = this.$router.resolve(route).href;
            link.innerText = params.value;
            link.addEventListener("click", e => {
              e.preventDefault();
              this.$router.push(route);
            });
            return link;
          }
},
```

Comment: This works for me too,Thanks.  But I want the Name field cells to be made clickable and not ID field. What to do for that? Any Idea.!